# How can I write this python input code? What I have gives me an error message

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code in a python file `first.py`

```
person=input("enter your name:")
print("helo ",person)
```

I expect it to return "helo person" with the name I enter but when input and press enter all I see is an error message that the name is not defined.

The code works perfectly well in thonny IDE but not in IDLE shell, can anyone who knows why help me?

I am a newcomer to programming.

Comment: Is that all the code? What is the error exactly? I can't see a problem or reproduce any error.

Comment: Please, explain more clear details of your error and what you actually did. The code above seems OK.

Comment: Me neither, the code runs just fine. No errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting such an error code, and it is working as expected in your other IDE, it appears that IDLE is using python 2.x, for which the input/print syntax has slightly different effects.

#### python 2

```
person = raw_input("enter your name: ")
print("hello {}".format(person))
```

#### python 3

```
person = input("enter your name: ")
print("hello ",person)
```

Comment: @iPython the OP may *think* they are, but running the code as they have written it above produces no errors on a python 3 environment, but does produce the `name '...' is not defined` error in a python 2 one.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `input` function with python 3 style but you are using python 2.7. Try:

```
person = raw_input("enter your name:")
print "Halo "+ person
```

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways to print what you want. Try:

```
print('helo %s' %person)
```

or

```
print('helo {}'.format(person))
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. And don't recommend `%` formatting. It's 2018, we should be recommending `f'hello {person}'`.

Comment: This is not the solution, even till now the question itself isn't clear. The code in the question seem fine.